# Reader error EOF when use os Pipe and bufio

Tags: go

today i doing code the sample code and appear one error,
special, I am using standard of golang.

```
r, w, err := os.Pipe()
fmt.Println("pipe err:", r, w, err)
bufr := bufio.NewReader(r)
s, err := bufr.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Println("ReadString.err", err)
fmt.Println("ReadString s", s)
```

At line 5, i see error EOF. please help and explain me.
thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of [`os.Pipe()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Pipe):

> Pipe returns a connected pair of Files; reads from r return bytes written to w. It returns the files and an error, if any.

You can read from `r` what you write to `w`. Do you see any writes in your code? Btw I get deadlock and not EOF when testing your code on the playground, and a blocking app locally.

If you do write something to `w`, you can read that:

```
r, w, err := os.Pipe()
fmt.Println("pipe err:", r, w, err)
go func() {
    fmt.Println(w.Write([]byte("hiho\n")))
}()
bufr := bufio.NewReader(r)
s, err := bufr.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Println("ReadString.err", err)
fmt.Println("ReadString s", s)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/fhPlZsS9kI5)):

```
pipe err: &{0xc0000b4120} &{0xc0000b4180} <nil>
5 <nil>
ReadString.err <nil>
ReadString s hiho
```

Comment: thanh you you answer, it is great